# Tcl seek and write in a file opened with 'a+'

Tags: tcl

I need to store some logs in a file that can grow with every execution. A logical way would be to use `a+` option when opening because using `w+` would truncate the file. However, with the `a+` option (Tcl 8.4) I cannot write anywhere in the file. `seek` works fine. I can verify that the pointer was moved using `tell`. But the output is always done at the **tail end** of the file.

Is there any way to resolve this? I.e. having the ability to seek and write in any place and also preserve the old file at the open.

Comment: Note that `open` supports another way of telling it the access mode , for instance you could call it like this: `open $fname {RDWR CREAT}` to get what you want.  But really `r+` is the way to go as @slebtman suggested.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In Tcl 8.5, the behavior of Tcl *on Unix* was changed so that the `O_APPEND` flag is passed to the `open()` system call. This causes the OS to always append the data to the file, and is inherited when the FD is passed to subprocesses; for logs, it is *exactly* the right thing. (In 8.4 and before, and in all versions on Windows, the behavior is simulated inside Tcl's file channel implementation, which will internally `seek()` to the end immediately before the `write()`; that obviously is subject to potential problems with race conditions when there are multiple processes logging to the same file and is definitely unsafe when the FD is passed to subprocesses.) You can manage truncation of the opened file with `chan truncate` (new in 8.5), which works just fine on `a+`-opened files.

If you do not want the seek-to-end behavior, you should not use `a+` (or `a`). Try `r+` or some combination of [flags](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.5/TclCmd/open.htm#M11), like this:

```
set f [open $filename {RDWR CREAT}]
```

For comparison, the `a+` option is now *exactly* the same as the flags `RDWR CREAT APPEND`, and not all combinations of longer flags can be described by short form flag specifiers. If you're not specifying `APPEND`, you'll need to do the `seek $f 0 end` yourself (and watch out for problems with multiple processes if you're appending to logs; that's when `APPEND` becomes required and exceptionally hard to correctly simulate any other way).

Comment: I've just found the (really ill-documented) `FILE_APPEND_DATA` flag to `CreateFile` might allow for proper appending on Windows. Or maybe not; it's really quite tricky to figure out what some things in the Win32 API actually do from its documentation…

Answer (score 3):

Open with `r+` - it opens in read mode (thus not turncating the file) but allows writing as well.

See the documentation of `open` for more info: http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.5/TclCmd/open.htm

Answer (score 0):

I have verified that using the `a+` option allow me to read/write anywhere in the file. However, by writing in the middle (or at the beginning) of a file, I overwrite the data there, not inserting. The following code illustrate that point:

```
#!/usr/bin/env tclsh

# Open the file, with truncation
set f [open foo w]
puts $f "one"
puts $f "two"
close $f

# Open again, with a+ ==> read/write/append
set f [open foo a+]
puts $f "three" ;# This goes to the end of the file
seek $f 4       ;# Seek to the beginning of the word "two"
puts $f "2.0"   ;# Overwrite the word "two"
close $f

# Open and verify the contents
set f [open foo r]
puts [read $f]
close $f
```

Output:

```
one
2.0
three
```

If you are looking to insert in the middle of the file, you might want to look at the `fileutil` package, which contains the `::fileutil::insertIntoFile` command.

Comment: I tried it with Tcl 8.4 and 8.5 on my Mac. What OS are you running on?

Comment: Linux 2.6.18-274.el5 #1 SMP Fri Jul 22 04:43:29 EDT 2011 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

Comment: Yeah, works for me on both 8.4 and 8.5 on Windows and 8.5 on Linux

Comment: Can you run `info patchlevel` on tcl and see what it says?

Comment: It also works on Red Hat: Linux autobot 2.6.9-89.0.11.ELsmp #1 SMP Mon Aug 31 11:01:10 EDT 2009 i686 i686 i386 GNU/Linux
and Tcl 8.4.19

Comment: `info patchlevel` returns 8.4.13